# Не работает margin в css

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, 3-й час мучаюсь, не могу понять, почему не работает выравнивание по правому краю:

```css
.sections {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
  float: left;
  border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  /* или */
  margin-left: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px;">
  <div class="sections">
    Hi
  </div>
  <div class="sections">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: inline-block;` для блоков отключить флоат и `text-align: right` родителю

```css
.sections {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
   border: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  /* или */
  margin-left: auto;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px; text-align: right">
  <div class="sections">
    Hi
  </div>
  <div class="sections">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется вы хотели добавить [`display: flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) родителю

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.section.right {
  margin-left: auto;
}


.section {
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="section">Hi</div>
  <div class="section right">Hello</div>
</div>
```